# Insert node at specific position

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

i need to insert a node at a given position in a linked list.
Is there any better way to do it?
Here is my code:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
void InsertNodeAtPosition(node *& first , int x , int position)
{

//0 based indexing
    int i = 0;
    node *q = new node;
    q = first;
    while (i != position - 1)
    {
      q = q->next;
      i++;
    }
    node *t = new node;
    t->data = x;
    t->next = q->next;
    q->next = t;
}
```

I tested it and it works.But i want to be really good at linked lists before moving to the next chapter.Thanks!

Comment: For things like linked lists, I always recommend starting out using pen and paper. Perform all operations by drawing on a few pieces of paper. Draw boxes for the nodes, and arrows for the links. Erase and redraw the arrows (links) as you modify them.

Comment: you are creating a new Node and then immediately drop the pointer to it, creating a memory leak, here: `node *q = new node; q = first;` this doesn't look right.

Comment: And when testing code, always use edge-cases (like `0` or the length of list minus one for indexes, using empty lists, one-node lists, two-node lists, three-node lists). And also test with *invalid* data (here your function will fail, try giving a `position` after the end of the list).

Comment: for reviews of code there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, though you are expected to post correct code there. Questions that ask for a review are typically too-broad or opinion-based for here

Comment: @idclev463035818 how do i do it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The written by you function is wrong has a memory leak and undefined behavior.

For example at first the pointer `q` is assigned with the address of the dynamically allocated memory and then it is reassigned with the value of the pointer `first`. So the address of the allocated memory is lost and the memory can not be freed.

```
node *q = new node;
q = first;
```

Moreover the pointer `first` passed to the function by reference is never changed within the function.

In the while loop you are not checking whether the pointer `q` is equal to `nullptr`

```
while (i != position - 1)
{
  q = q->next;
  i++;
}
```

So this statement

```
q = q->next;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Also if `position` is equal to `0` then the condition

```
i != position - 1
```

will evaluate to true and again you will have undefined behavior.

The function can be written the following way

```
void InsertNodeAtPosition( node * &first , int x , size_t position )
{
    node **current = &first;

    while ( *current && position-- )
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    *current = new node { x, *current };
}
```

Comment: What did you even do ..... I understand the first part of your answer , but your function is far beyond me XD

Comment: @CosminAndrei I declared a pointer to the pointer first. That is now the pointer first is accessed by reference in the C meaning.  Dereferencing the pointer current I can change the pointer first or any data member next of the current node. The while loop is executed until either the current pointer is equal to nullptr or position is equal to 0. After that a new node is dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any better way to do it?

Certainly, it would be better to not leak memory:

```
node *q = new node;
q = first;
```

As for the algorithm itself: For a singly linked list, a better way to insert an element into specific position is to pass a pointer to the previous node as the argument rather than the head and the position. That way there is no need for linear search. But for given arguments, your attempted algorithm is optimal.

As for class design: A better way is to implement iterators for the list and use those instead of pointers to nodes so that standard algorithms can be used. And follow the rule of 5 in order to conform to the RAII pattern and container concept. And use templates to support different data types. And support the use of custom allocators so that user have control over how the nodes are allocated.

As for higher level design: A better way to use a singly linked list is to not do any of this since the standard library already provides an implementation of the data structure: `std::forward_list`.

Comment: how can i avoid the leak of memory?

Comment: @CosminAndrei Don't create a node that you don't use. Count the number of `new` in your function. Count how many nodes your function is supposed to insert into the list.

Comment: @CosminAnrei you create a new Node and don't do anything with it, so just don't create it

Comment: With the node q  i go stop right before the node at the given position , and then  i insert the node t...How can i do it otherwise?

Comment: @CosminAndrei q and t are not nodes. They are pointers to nodes. q points to several different nodes while you are iterating. `How can i do it otherwise?` I suggested an alternative algorithm in the answer. If you pass a pointer to previous node directly into the function, then you can do the insertion without the linear search.

Comment: @eerorika sorry , I think I'm missing something.So , when i create a linked list , it is allocated in the heap memory,right?When i declare the pointer q,its value will be the adress of my first node.I don't exactly understand the 'new' issue.Should i put node* q = first , without the new?

Comment: @CosminAndrei `new` is a keyword that creates a dynamic object. Unless that object is de-allocated with the `delete` keyword, that object leaks. You use `new`, then throw away the pointer value that you got from it immediately afterwards when you assign `q`. That is always a memory leak. `Should i put node* q = first , without the new?` Yes. If you don't intend to create an object, then don't create an object.

Comment: And,i should declare with 'new' only the node i want to insert , right?The other one which iterates is just a pointer?

Comment: @CosminAndrei Both pointers are just pointers. You should create one node if you intend to insert one node into the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223618/discussion-between-cosminandrei-and-eerorika).